# Count occurance in a row in SQLite just by SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a DB contain 5 columns, all are integers range from 1~5 e.g.
1,1,2,3,1
5,1,2,3,4
4,2,3,2,1
....
is there a way to count number of occurrence of, say 1 in first row by just SQL ? (in this case, 3 should be return). select count() just deal with number of records return in column manner. Thanks.

Regds
LAM Chi-fung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine case with count to get five columns, each with the count of the values 1 - 5:

```sql
select
     case when col1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end + case when col2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end + case when col3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end + case when col4 = 1 then 1 else 0 end + case when col5 = 1 then 1 else 0 end as count_1
    ,case when col1 = 2 then 1 else 0 end + case when col2 = 2 then 1 else 0 end + case when col3 = 2 then 1 else 0 end + case when col4 = 2 then 1 else 0 end + case when col5 = 2 then 1 else 0 end as count_2
    ,case when col1 = 3 then 1 else 0 end + case when col2 = 3 then 1 else 0 end + case when col3 = 3 then 1 else 0 end + case when col4 = 3 then 1 else 0 end + case when col5 = 3 then 1 else 0 end as count_3
    ,case when col1 = 4 then 1 else 0 end + case when col2 = 4 then 1 else 0 end + case when col3 = 4 then 1 else 0 end + case when col4 = 4 then 1 else 0 end + case when col5 = 4 then 1 else 0 end as count_4
    ,case when col1 = 5 then 1 else 0 end + case when col2 = 5 then 1 else 0 end + case when col3 = 5 then 1 else 0 end + case when col4 = 5 then 1 else 0 end + case when col5 = 5 then 1 else 0 end as count_5
from table_x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select t.*,
       (col1 = 1) + (col2 = 1) + (col3 = 1) + (col4 = 1) + (col5 = 1) as num_1s
from t
```

SQLite treats boolean expressions like numbers in an arithmetic context, with `1` for true and `0` for false.  You can also express this more verbosely as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when col1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when col2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when col3 = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when col4 = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when col5 = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
       ) as num_1s
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

By unpivoting the data, you can get the count for all values in all columns in a single query, without the need to know the possible values in advance

```
sqlite> select * from t;
col1        col2        col3        col4        col5
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           2           3           1
5           1           2           3           4
4           2           3           2           1
sqlite> select      col
   ...>            ,count(*) as cnt
   ...> from        (           select col1 as col  from t
   ...>             union all   select col2         from t
   ...>             union all   select col3         from t
   ...>             union all   select col4         from t
   ...>             union all   select col5         from t
   ...>             )
   ...> group by    col
   ...> ;
col         cnt
----------  ----------
1           5
2           4
3           3
4           2
5           1
sqlite>
```